# Laravel - Two @yield working while third one doesn't

Tags: php, laravel

I have this layouts:

[image]

Where in app.blade.php I have three @yield tags like this:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
@yield('title')
...
@yield('content')
...
@yield('calcscript')
...
</body>
</html>
```

and in my nav.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
    <h3>some title</h3>
@endsection

@section('content')
    a simple html code

@endsection
@section('calcscript')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        some javascript code
    </script>
    <style>
        some css style
    </style>
@endsection
```

The problem is that it returns the calcscript and content yields, but it doesn't return the title yield. It's so strange.
I tried to clear laravel's cache and view cache. But it didn't work.

Comment: It actually shound't return the **calcscript** since you're yielding **script** in your app.blade.php. Strange...

Comment: @Tushar sorry, it was a typo when writing in stackoverflow.

Comment: ```@section('title')
 some title
@endsection```

try This

Comment: @SahilGupta not making any difference

Comment: Long shot, but try actually putting some properly formatted html in the content section...

Comment: In theory, what you have should work in my experience.